# How to refer to previous items in array dynamically, without using "i-1", "i-2", etc.?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, object

```js
function play_music(song) {
  let played_notes = [];
  let secs = [];
  let position = [];
  let secs_to_wait = 0;
  let time_elapsed = 0;

  console.log("Song started.")

  for (let key in song) {
    played_notes.push(song[key].note);
    secs.push(song[key].lasts);
    position.push(song[key].starts_at);
  }

  for (let i in position) {
    if (position[i] > position[i - 1]) {
      secs_to_wait = position[i] - secs_to_wait;
      console.log("Wait " + secs_to_wait + " second(s).");
      console.log("Play " + played_notes[i]);
    } else {
      console.log("Play " + played_notes[i]);
    }

    if (position[i] == position[i - 1] && secs[i] == secs[i - 1] || position[i] + secs[i] == secs[i - 1]) {
      //do nothing.
    } else {
      time_elapsed += secs[i];
    }

    if ((secs[i] + position[i]) < time_elapsed || secs[i] < time_elapsed) {
      console.log(played_notes[i] + " released.")
    }
  }
  return "Song ends.";
}

let my_song = [{
    note: 'C',
    starts_at: 0,
    lasts: 4
  },
  {
    note: 'E',
    starts_at: 0,
    lasts: 4
  },
  {
    note: 'G',
    starts_at: 2,
    lasts: 2
  },
  {
    note: 'G#',
    starts_at: 3,
    lasts: 2
  },
  {
    note: 'Eb',
    starts_at: 3,
    lasts: 2
  }
];

console.log(play_music(my_song))
```

In this program I am supposed to make a function which returns console messages of musical notes from an array of objects chronologically, when they start, how much time to wait between them, and when to release those notes. I have three elements in each object: the musical note name, starting position in seconds, and how long it lasts (also in seconds).

My code works 90% when I go through each element by index, but when I get to return "release" messages on the console, I can't refer to musical notes that come before the index I'm in. And if I just put the following, it will only work for the current order of elements, it won't work dynamically, regardless of order:

```js
  if ((secs[i] + position[i]) < time_elapsed || secs[i] < time_elapsed){
     console.log((played_notes[i] + played_notes[i-1] + played_notes[i-2]) + " released.")
  }
```

For now if you run the entire code shown previously, only "G" will be released, "C" and "E" don't get released. And later, "G#" and "Eb" don't get released simultaneously, but rather "G#" plays and gets released, and just later "Eb" plays and gets released.

Not to mention that I don't get the "Wait x second(s)." message before "G#" and "Eb" are played.

So something is not working, and the console output I'm expecting to get at the end is like this:

```
Song started.
Play C
Play E
Wait 2 second(s).
Play G
Wait 1 second(s).
Play G#   
Play Eb
C released.
E released.
G released.
Wait 1 second(s).
G# released.
Eb released.
Song ends.
```

NOTE: I am a beginner, and for this task I am not allowed to use anything more advanced than for loops, while loops, if statements, array and object built-in functions. So foreach or anything beyond that won't cut it. Please try to keep it as simple as possible in this sense, it may require a longer answer.

Comment: There's no other way than using `i-1` as the index. But you need to check that `i-1` is in the array. If you're currently on the first element, there's no previous element.

Comment: There's no good reason for those 3 arrays. You can just do everything using the `song` array.

Comment: Actually I'm on the third element when I get to G, as the order of notes within the object is C, E, G. What I'm lost about is how to refer to C and E.

Comment: You should sort the array into the proper order so that `i-1` and `i-2` access the correct order.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, it wouldn't work dynamically as I need it to work, only with this particular order of notes and time intervals. The idea is that the program analyses the notes and knows when each of them play, how long to wait between them and when to release chronologically regardless of order. It shouldn't depend on having a certain order of elements.

Comment: It doesn't depend on them being in a particular order, it reorders them.

Comment: Sorry, but it's just hard for me to picture all of this. Would you mind giving me a code snippet example to make it clearer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array first so that they're in order of position. Then the previous note will always be the one with the previous index.

```js
function play_music(song) {
  let played_notes = [];
  let secs = [];
  let position = [];
  let secs_to_wait = 0;
  let time_elapsed = 0;

  console.log("Song started.")

  // Sort song in order of start. Notes that start at the same time are in order of duration
  song.sort((a, b) => a.starts_at - b.starts_at || a.lasts - b.lasts);

  for (let key in song) {
    played_notes.push(song[key].note);
    secs.push(song[key].lasts);
    position.push(song[key].starts_at);
  }

  for (let i in position) {
    if (position[i] > position[i - 1]) {
      secs_to_wait = position[i] - secs_to_wait;
      console.log("Wait " + secs_to_wait + " second(s).");
      console.log("Play " + played_notes[i]);
    } else {
      console.log("Play " + played_notes[i]);
    }

    if (position[i] == position[i - 1] && secs[i] == secs[i - 1] || position[i] + secs[i] == secs[i - 1]) {
      //do nothing.
    } else {
      time_elapsed += secs[i];
    }

    if ((secs[i] + position[i]) < time_elapsed || secs[i] < time_elapsed) {
      console.log(played_notes[i] + " released.")
    }
  }
  return "Song ends.";
}

let my_song = [{
    note: 'C',
    starts_at: 0,
    lasts: 4
  },
  {
    note: 'E',
    starts_at: 0,
    lasts: 4
  },
  {
    note: 'G',
    starts_at: 2,
    lasts: 2
  },
  {
    note: 'G#',
    starts_at: 3,
    lasts: 2
  },
  {
    note: 'Eb',
    starts_at: 3,
    lasts: 2
  }
];

console.log(play_music(my_song))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar is correct, sorting is needed to keep the starts_at in order or else the wait wouldnt work if a song is passed in with notes set incorrectly.  This answer should match exactly the expected output without using i-1 i-2 etc.  Fun exercise thanks.

```js
function play_music(song) { 
    let elapsedInSeconds = -1; //song running time -1 song havent started yet
    let waitTimeInSeconds = 0; //wait time
    let songLengthInSeconds = -1; //total song length
    let noteToPlayIndex = 0; //note index to play in song

    song.sort((a, b) => {
        //the song total length will be the last note starts and how long it lasts
        const aNoteLengthInSeconds = a.starts_at + a.lasts;
        const bNoteLengthInSeconds = b.starts_at + b.lasts;
        //inject this here so we dont have to waste another loop
        songLengthInSeconds = Math.max(songLengthInSeconds, aNoteLengthInSeconds, bNoteLengthInSeconds);
        //we make sure the last note with longest duration be at the bottom of list
        return a.starts_at - b.starts_at || aNoteLengthInSeconds - bNoteLengthInSeconds; //a.lasts - b.lasts would work too
    });

    console.log('Song started.');
    //play until the end of the song
    while(elapsedInSeconds < songLengthInSeconds) {
        elapsedInSeconds++;
        //when we wait, a second went by so subtract and prevent going below 0
        waitTimeInSeconds = Math.max(0, --waitTimeInSeconds);
        //keep track if this is a waiting tick, we would need to track which keys needed to be released
        let isWaitingTick = waitTimeInSeconds > 0;
        for (let i=0; i < song.length; i++) {
            //if its waiting tick, we don't need to loop through the keys we haven't played
            if (isWaitingTick && i >= noteToPlayIndex) {
                break;
            }
            
            //keep track of the time that we need to release the keys
            const keyReleasedAt = song[i].starts_at + song[i].lasts;

            //doesnt matter if we are in waiting tick or not, if its ready to be release, then release it
            if (keyReleasedAt == elapsedInSeconds) { 
                console.log(song[i].note + " released.");
            }else if (!isWaitingTick) { 
                //play the key if its exact second to play
                if (song[i].starts_at == elapsedInSeconds) {
                    console.log("Play " + song[i].note, song[i].lasts);
                    noteToPlayIndex++;
                //other wise if it needs wait some time, we set our wait timer    
                } else if (song[i].starts_at > elapsedInSeconds) {
                    waitTimeInSeconds = song[i].starts_at - elapsedInSeconds;
                    console.log("Wait " + waitTimeInSeconds + " second(s).");
                    //break so it doesnt look at other notes; other keys would be >= of this note starts_at because of sort
                    break; 
                    
                //if we played all the keys then we should see if we need to wait any time for it to be released
                }  else if ( noteToPlayIndex >= song.length && keyReleasedAt > elapsedInSeconds) {
                    //wait time should be the diff between the second of the song it supposed to be released and current elapse time 
                    waitTimeInSeconds = keyReleasedAt - elapsedInSeconds;
                    console.log("Wait " + waitTimeInSeconds + " second(s).");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "Song ends.";
}

let my_song = [
    {
        note: 'C',
        starts_at: 0,
        lasts: 4
    },
    {
        note: 'E',
        starts_at: 0,
        lasts: 4
    },
    {
        note: 'G',
        starts_at: 2,
        lasts: 2
    },

    {
        note: 'G#',
        starts_at: 3,
        lasts: 2
    },
    {
        note: 'Eb',
        starts_at: 3,
        lasts: 2
    },
];

console.log(play_music(my_song));
```